# What are heads that aren't branches?

Tags: git

I noticed that my git repository has several files under `logs/refs/heads/` that don't show up when I run `git branch -a`.  The filenames look like branches that I deleted long ago.  Why do they still show up in `logs/refs/heads`?  Can they safely be deleted?  Why didn't git delete them?

Comment: http://alblue.bandlem.com/2011/08/git-tip-of-week-detached-heads.html

Answer (score 1):

Actually the more appropriate blog link is: http://alblue.bandlem.com/2011/05/git-tip-of-week-reflogs.html

These are your reflogs, or logs of how your branch pointers were moved from commit to commit.

The heads are in just `/refs` not `/logs/refs`.

See also information about the `git reflog` command (including the `expire` subcommand to clean them up) here: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog